# Thymeleaf - problem with th:href="@{/css/style.css}"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I know this is another question about Thymeleaf & CSS, but:

```
<span>© 2020-<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/year.js}"></script> created by:</span>
```

it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bulma/0.8.1/css/bulma.min.css}"/>
```

it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
```

**it doesn't work.**

why?

Everything is set up well

```
(.antMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/webjars/**")
```

In Chrome there is error:

Refused to apply style from `http://localhost:8080/static/css/style.css` because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Why 'application/json' ?

Interesting thing is at address: `http://localhost:8080/css/style.css` I can see my CSS code, but somehow Thymeleaf generate form above `<link>` tag wrong address: `http://localhost:8080/static/css/style.css`

Comment: You get that MIME type error because spring will return a JSON object saying 404 or whatever because it can't find the file. It shouldn't include static. If you just use `href="/css/style.css"` it should work fine. Although if you had a prefix(deployed with some context) you would have to just configure so it doesn't prepend `static` and use `@{...}`

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML in the web browser (using View Source), what do those lines say? Edit the question and show us that result of the Thymeleaf template.

Comment: I must say that I didn't notice that I had an additional `<link>` tag in the code (```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css"/>```). But thanks to you I see the mistake. Thanks a lot!